# PrestaShop Call to undefined method FrontController::parseCMSContent() after update to 1.7.8.2

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I created some custom shortcodes for my PrestaShop by creating a file (**override/classes/controller/FrontController.php**) with a method like :

```
public static function parseCMSContent($content)
{
...
}
```

And in my module and cms smarty templates I changed:

```
{$cms.content nofilter}
```

to:

```
{FrontController::parseCMSContent($cms.content) nofilter}
```

Everything was working fine with Prestashop 1.7.7.5, but the update to 1.7.8.2 broke the whole thing.

I get a 500 error saying :

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method FrontController::parseCMSContent() ... .module.pscustomtextpscustomtext. ...
```

It's still working fine with debug mode enabled though..

I can't find anything about the function being deprecated, any idea on how I could get this working again please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this can help anyone, I fixed this by moving my override into a new smarty plugin.

I created a file **vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/plugins/function.get_shortcoded_content.php**

I added my shortcodes in:

```
function smarty_function_get_shortcoded_content($params, &$smarty)
{
...
}
```

And in my smarty files I called:

```
{get_shortcoded_content content=$cms.content}
```

instead of:

```
{$cms.content nofilter}
```

It seems to work all fine again.